# How to create a formula field to add seconds to the standard CreatedDate field in an Object?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have this easy requirement where they want a field that displays the the CreatedDate field of the object but with seconds at the end.

[image]

I've created a formula field

[image]

but it's still showing like in the first image, no seconds added ....

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer that may not meet your requirements

```
TEXT(Day( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) )) & "/" &
TEXT(Month( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ))&"/"&
TEXT(Year( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) )) & " " &
MID(TEXT(CreatedDate),12,8) & 
' UTC'
```

will display result in 24 hr time, UTC (not local time). For example:

```
25/11/2020 16:22:33 UTC
```

Comment: Bro, this kinda worked !!! Thank you so much .... Question ... why is it displayin the time in UTC and not in Local Time ? Is there a way to display it in local time ?

Comment: Datetimes are stored as UTC and TEXT function grabs that.

Comment: Hi cropredy, I thought you might be able to help me with this question too: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327425/date-time-formula-from-formula-not-showing-any-value?noredirect=1#comment484862_327425

Comment: Because what I really really need is to have the createdDate value in a new Date/Time variable, not a text one ... is there any way to achieve this with a formula ?